# DevExpress ExpressSkins or VCL Styles?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I am working on a big legacy application written in Delphi. Most of the components are VCL and DevExpress QuantumGrid components. 
I would need to update the UI to support various styles and a more modern look and feel. Originally 
I was planning to switch to the DevExpress ExpressSkins library (I already have the full DevExpress VCL subscription) and replace all components with DevExpress components. However since than I have upgraded the project to Delphi XE2 and with it came the VCL Styles technology.

What are the pros and cons of these libraries?

Comment: I doubt VCL styles will work properly with the QuantumGrid and other DevExpress components so use ExpressSkins I'd say. At all I always prefer the DevExpress component over the VCL one when available.

Comment: Replacing all your controls with DevExpress controls may actually be more work than it's worth, and while Stefan and David have a point, I really think that the bottom line is that you are setting yourself up for disappointment either way you go.  Perfect-skinning is a pipe dream, but if you really must do skinning, as of today's date, Express Skins is more mature and less buggy.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used VCL styles because I too have Dev Express and like to use their skins. But here are my two cents for DX skins.

Pros for DX skins:

- look great
- always coming out with more skins
- styles chooser widget built in for the end user, if you use the DX ribbon in your app
- DX has great support for their components

Cons for DX skins:

- unusable in a Citrix or Terminal Services environment due to slow screen painting
- each skin adds an entry to your USES clause which can be cumbersome for version control

Comment: I think the automatic skin unit adding can be disabled in the skin options. Then if you want to include skins it can be done in a separate unit.